# C# Looping [Index was out of range]

Tags: c#

I have a Loop like this

```
int numberofelements=20;

for(int i=0;i<numberofelements;i++)
            {

                if(i==numberofelements)
                {
                    break;
                }

                if(i==i+1))
                {
                   //do some thing

                }else
                {
                  //do some thing else

                }

        }
```

As obvious this gives the runtime exception for the final element of the list: `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.`

how do i handle this on the last element of this list not to check the condition `i==i+1`?

Comment: i  think `i == numberofelements - 1`, also `i==numberofelements` won't be executed since you loop for `< numberofelements`

Comment: Can't you just do `i <= numberofelements`?

Comment: @DMan I used but i had the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberofelements - 1; i++)
{
    // do something
}

// do something else with numberofelements - 1
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like your trying to get an Elemrnt of a List which contains less than 20 elements, you will have to show some more code what are you doing with i in the loop.

Besides you need only the **else** part since the other ones will never be true:

"**i**" can not be equal to "**i+1**" and will will never be equal to **numberofelements** because of your loop limitis (i < numberofelements)

You can access all elements by:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) // Loop through List with for
{
   // do something with list[i]
}
```

Comment: "i" can not be equal to "i+1", exactly +1

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are loop is correct for 20 elements

```
for(int i=0;i<numberofelements;i++)
```

But for the last element you would need to check `i == numberofelements - 1` which would be index 19.

Also no need for

```
if(i==numberofelements)
{
    break;
}
```

as i never equals numberofelements which is 20

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem is that your first if-statement will never get used. The for-loop will exit before i equals numOfElements (unless you modify i inside the for-loop).

So you could do something like:

```
if (i == (numOfElements - 1)) {
    // do something
    break;
}
```

And that would make it so that you wouldn't get the null pointer error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.....

```
  int numberofelements=20;

            for (int i = 0; i < numberofelements; i++)
            {

                if (i == numberofelements - 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("last element" + i);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {

                    if (i == i + 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(i);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(i);
                    }
                }
}
```